# How to catch this JavaFX NullPointerException that occurs once a Canvas gets too large?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

In JavaFX there is an issue once a Canvas gets too large because the texture is too large to be processed by the application. In my case this issue is reached once the Canvas dimension is >= 8192.

That's totally fine if I could catch the exception that is thrown then.

The exception looks like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderBuf.validate(NGCanvas.java:213)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.initCanvas(NGCanvas.java:640)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:603)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderForClip(NGNode.java:2294)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderRectClip(NGNode.java:2188)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderClip(NGNode.java:2214)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.CacheFilter.impl_renderNodeToCache(CacheFilter.java:671)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.CacheFilter.render(CacheFilter.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderCached(NGNode.java:2358)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2044)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:577)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Its been thrown by some JavaFX background thread, but I have no idea how to intercept it. So far I've tried Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() but it won't intercept the exception.

I could simply check if the dimension gets >= 8192 but other users might have a smaller maximum supported texture resolution and trigger the exception earlier.

I won't use this approach forever, once I have time I will work on a solution that uses tiling but it would be nice if I could catch the exception at the moment. It's only for a hobby project but it's still annoying.

Comment: An NPE is an unchecked exception, meaning you shouldn't catch it.

Comment: The application is not responding as long as the Canvas is in this state. What I would like to do is catch the NPE once it occurs and set dimension to something smaller so the canvas can function again.

Comment: AFAIK the issue is related to the maximum texture size, not to the VRAM. (At least there's a similar issue that I know of...)

Comment: That indeed seems to be the issue. But I guess there is no way to request the maximum possible texture size at runtime.

Comment: These issues seem related to this: [JDK-8090178](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090178) and [JDK-8089835](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089835).